# Why is Version.Minor of Windows Phone OS 7.1 "10"?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

A Mango phone (Windows Phone 7.5/Windows Phone OS 7.1) at my hand says "7.**10**.XXXX" when I executed the following code:

```
System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString()
```

I expected "7.**1**.XXXX".

Why is the minor version number (the second number) "10" (not "1")?

Is there any convention to interpret "10" as "1" ???

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of any such convention;  To clarify, this is how I understand it:

- In consumer/marketing land, Windows Phone Mango is Windows Phone 7.5.
- In developer land, the assemblies are Windows Phone 7.1, and more
  importantly the SDK is 7.1
- In OS Build land, 7.10.7720.68 is Mango
  RTM.

Having said that, you can equate 7.10.7720 to Mango / 7.1 / 7.5 - but 7.10.8200 has been spotted in the wild, but unconfirmed whether it's Tango or Mango.

*To answer your question*: Pretty sure there's no convention to read 10 as 1.

Comment: When looking through different versions of programs, you normally compare first the major version number, then the minor version number...separated by dots, not just treated like single-character entities. You shouldn't actually skip between, say, 7.1 to 7.15 to 7.2. Not like I can actually explain why WP7 is...